# Magento checkout page login issue 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento

I am having an issue with login. After coming to onepage checkout page, if customer registers or logs in using username and password, customer is TAKEN back to SHOPPING CART. This happens with both while registering and also for existing customer. The magento version is 1.8.0.0 and custom theme does have customer, checkout, persistent folders, i.e, it uses base templates. Please help with this.

Comment: Did you check var/log exception?

Comment: It is not generating any exception, it would simply go back to cart page once customer logs in at checkout page.

Comment: it seemed to be more of cookie session issue, had to mention domain name and cookie session value in admin section. Solved the issue.